# How to write resolve graphql filters in apollo graphql server

Tags: sequelize.js, graphql, apollo-server

## Requirement:

I need recommendation in writing resolver function for handling graphql filters. The filter supports eq, ne, like, contains and not like operators.

### Schema:

```
import { gql } from 'apollo-server-express';

export default gql`
   extend type Query {
       authGroups(filter: AuthGroupFilterInput): AuthGroupConnection!
    }

    type AuthGroup implements Node {
       id: ID!
       name: String
    }

    input AuthGroupFilterInput {
       name: StringFilterInput
    }

    type AuthGroupConnection {
       edges: [AuthGroup!]!
       pageInfo: PageInfo
    }

    input StringFilterInput {
      lt: String,
      gt: String,
      eq: String,
      ne: String,
      contains: String,
      like: String,
      notLike: String,
    }  

`;
```

### GraphQL Query:

```
 Query {
    authGroups(filter: {  
          name: {
             like: '%AD'
          }
       }
      )
    {
       edges {
         id
         name
       }
    }
 }
```

### Resolvers:

```
authGroups: async (parent, args, { models }) => {
        const filter = args.filter;
        const filters = filter 
                        ? {
                            where: filter,
                        } 
                        : {};

        const authGroups = await models.authGroup.findAll({
           ...filters
        //    where : {
        //        name: {
        //            [Sequelize.Op.like] : 'AD%'
        //        }
        //    }
        });  
}
```

### Technologies Used:

- Apollo Server
- express
- Sequelize
- PostgreSQL

How to replace the operators in filter with [Sequelize.Op.operator]? I tried using operatorsAliases in config.json but it didn't have any effect. Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use bracket notation to access the correct property on `Op`. Something like this:

```
function transformFilter (filter) {
  for (const fieldName in filter) {
    const condition = filter[fieldName]
    filter[fieldName] = {}
    for (const operatorName in condition) {
      filter[fieldName][Op[operatorName]] = condition[operatorName]
    }
  }
}
```

Bracket notation works even when it's "nested" like this.

Comment: My laptop has crashed and i am in the process of recovering the data. I will revert to you after i try this solution.

Comment: This function worked for me and i prefer this approach as operatorsaliases is not highly recommended. How do we extend this function to support OR operator?

Comment: Adding operators like `and` or `or` would require much more complex logic. In fact, it would probably require you to revise how you've set up your schema. That's really outside the scope of this question. Take a look at [how Graphcool does it](https://www.graph.cool/docs/reference/graphql-api/query-api-nia9nushae#filtering-by-field) for some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem with OperatorAliases by passing it in Sequelize constructor.

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
const operatorsAliases = {
    eq: Op.eq,
    ne: Op.ne,
    gte: Op.gte,
    gt: Op.gt,
    lte: Op.lte,
    lt: Op.lt,
    ......
}
```

Use this Aliases in sequelize while connecting..

```
const dbService = {
    connect: (host, database) => {
        const sequelize = new Sequelize(
            database,
            user,
            pwd, {
                host: host,
                dialect: 'yourDialect',
                dialectOptions: {
                    domain: domain,
                    encrypt: true
                },
                operatorsAliases: operatorsAliases,
                pool: {
                    max: 100,
                    min: 10,
                    idle: 200
                }
            }
        );

        sequelize
            .authenticate()
            .then(() => {
                console.log(database, 'Connection has been established successfully.');
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error(err, `Unable to connect to the database.`);
            });

        return sequelize;
    }
};
const yourDBRef = dbService.connect(hostName, dbName);
```

And it should work directly in your resolver without any extra effort.

```
  const authGroups = await models.authGroup.findAll({
        where :filters
    });
```

Comment: My laptop has crashed and i am in the process of recovering the data. I will revert to you after i try this solution.

Comment: Thanks Amit this solution worked for me too. I did a mistake of defining operatorsaliases in config file. I moved the operatorsaliases to the place where sequelize instance is created and it worked.